# Class self association in MetaUML

Tags: latex

Is it possible to draw a self referencial association at one specific class in MetaUML?
Suppose i have the Class item:

```
Class.Item("Item")()();
```

and want to add a self refencing assocaition to itself using:

```
 clink(association)(Item,Item);
```

But this won't work (nothing is displayed). What is the correct way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
input metauml;
beginfig(1);
    Class.A("Tree")()();
    drawObjects(A);
    link(aggregationUni)(A.e -- A.e+(30,0) -- (A.right+30,A.bottom-40) -- A.s+(0,-40) -- A.s);
endfig;
end
```

For this particular scenario, you need to create the link path by hand.

More common types of link paths can be created with the macros described in the manual, section 9 - Drawing Paths.